# How to redirect all requests to a file, except images using Apache?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, front-controller

I have an .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

With this, I want *all* requests to be redirected to the file `entryPoint.php` so that it can examine them:

- If there is no extension, is must be a module
- If there's a .php, it's a hacking
- If it's a .png, then it's a "safe" call.

  In case of images, I used to output headers, and `file_get_contents()` their content. I figured out it's a bit slower than leaving a *direct* read.

### My question is:

How to prevent this .htaccess from calling `entryPoint.php` if there are references for images?

<sup>Extra feedback on the code I already have is greatly appreciated!</sup>

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As I understand you want to process all non-images threw your php file. Right?

If so, then here is what you need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
RewriteRule (.*)  entryPoint.php [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Remember to add to delete any image extension you want!
If I misunderstood,Please tell me to correct my answer!

Comment: nope, I want to process everything through that file EXCEPT images :)

Comment: thats right, it works now, but whats the difference between:

RewriteRule (.*)  entryPoint.php [QSA] and
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA]

Comment: @user893856 there is no different because both rewrite all path!

Comment: newb question: can someone tell me where to put this file? at document root?

Comment: @philx_x  Yes, that would do the job.

Comment: I would add CSS and JS to keep some stylesheet and javascript to work on a maintenance page: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js)$`

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like this to stop rewriting images

```
RewriteRule \.(jpg|png)$ - [L]
```

This rule says 'if the requested file ends with a period followed by either "jpg" or "png" then don't rewrite it.'

The `$` character just marks "the end of the string/filename", the `-` says "don't rewrite the URL if this rule matches", and the `[L]` means "don't process any more rules if this one matches.

I'll add that the usual way of dealing with this sort of thing is to just apply a blanket statement of "if this file exists just serve the file up directly, but anything that doesn't exist gets processed by PHP." That type of rule looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This says "if the request isn't for a file or directory that exists, pass the request to index.php with the original path passed as a query string parameter called 'request', appending any other query string parameters to the new request."

Comment: Don't forget `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l` for symbolic links

Answer (score 7):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|jpg|gif)$
```

Put this line right before your `RewriteRule`