# Htaccess redirect all requests to index (does not allow images) Wamp Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wampserver, front-controller

Please I need a help. I am working on a site and wants to redirect all requests to an index file while allowing access to images, css, javascripts and other documents that are not php scripts. I am working on a local server (WAMP). The problem I have is that it redirects all requests to the index file including images. Below is my htaccess rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /myapp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([^/]+)/?$ app/$1-$2/$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect all requests to a file, except images using Apache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060932/how-to-redirect-all-requests-to-a-file-except-images-using-apache)

Answer (score 0):

Is this not what you're aiming for?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ index.php [L]
```

You should also escape those slashes in your first rewrite rule

Comment: Thanks @kieran but I want to use SEO friendly urls, the index file will process the request and include the required page. Your suggestion seem to redirect only files that end with .php

Comment: @andychukse you need a set to work with, either file types to redirect on or file types not to redirect on so please define "other documents"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have figured it out, I just modified the moved the first rewrite rule above the rewrite condition and it now working fine.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /myapp
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([^/]+)/?$ app/$1-$2/$3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```